# select first occurrence of variable with prefix in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the best way to `dplyr::select` the first occurrence of a variable with a certain prefix (and all other variables without that prefix). Or put another way, drop all variables with that prefix except the first occurrence.

```
library(tidyverse)
hiris <- head(iris)
#given this data.frame:
lst(hiris, hiris, hiris) %>% 
  map(rownames_to_column) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = "rowname")

#   rowname Sepal.Length.x Sepal.Width.x Petal.Length.x Petal.Width.x Species.x Sepal.Length.y Sepal.Width.y Petal.Length.y Petal.Width.y Species.y Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1       1            5.1           3.5            1.4           0.2    setosa            5.1           3.5            1.4           0.2    setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2       2            4.9           3.0            1.4           0.2    setosa            4.9           3.0            1.4           0.2    setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3       3            4.7           3.2            1.3           0.2    setosa            4.7           3.2            1.3           0.2    setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4       4            4.6           3.1            1.5           0.2    setosa            4.6           3.1            1.5           0.2    setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5       5            5.0           3.6            1.4           0.2    setosa            5.0           3.6            1.4           0.2    setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6       6            5.4           3.9            1.7           0.4    setosa            5.4           3.9            1.7           0.4    setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Now lets say I want to drop all variables with prefix `Sepal.Length` except the first one (`Sepal.Length.x`) I could do:

```
lst(hiris, hiris, hiris) %>% 
  map(rownames_to_column) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = "rowname") %>%
  dplyr::select(-Sepal.Length.y, -Sepal.Length)
```

which works fine but I want something flexible so it will work with an arbitrary number of variables with prefix `Sepal.Length` e.g.:

```
lst(hiris, hiris, hiris, hiris, hiris, hiris, hiris) %>% 
  map(rownames_to_column) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = "rowname")
```

I could do something like this:

```
df <- lst(hiris, hiris, hiris, hiris, hiris, hiris, hiris) %>% 
  map(rownames_to_column) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = "rowname")
name_drop <- (df %>% select(matches("Sepal.Length")) %>% names())[-1]
df %>% 
  select(-name_drop)
```

but im looking to do it in a pipe and more efficiently. any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this explanation of the problem:

> drop all variables with that prefix except the first occurrence.

```
select(iris, !starts_with("Sepal")[-1])
#     Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 1            5.1          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 2            4.9          1.4         0.2     setosa
# ...
```

`starts_with("Sepal")` of course returns all  columns that start with `"Sepal"`, we can use `[-1]` to remove the first match, and `!` to drop any remaining matches.

It does seem a little like black magic - if we were doing this in base R, the `[-1]` would be appropriate if we used `which()` to get column indices, and the `!` would be appropriate if we didn't use `which()` and had a logical vector, but somehow the `tidyselect` functionality makes it work!

Comment: awhhh..so so simple

Comment: I wasn't confident it would work until I tried it... and it does!

Comment: and the opposite for anyone who might need it as I did, the last occurrence: `select(!starts_with("Sepal")[-length(starts_with("Sepal"))])`

Comment: `head(x, -1)` is a nice pattern for omitting the last value - `select(!head(starts_with("Sepal"), -1))` for the last occurrence.